# PHP form - echo out array of values

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a from which fetched basic fields but I would like to put in some values which are arrays.  Here is an example of the post data when the form is submitted.

```
successArray ( 
    [rsvpname] => wewqewqe 
    [rsvpemail] => ewwqe@ffdfs.com 
    [rsvpphone] => 23232 
    [rsvpcomments] => 21321 
    [guests] => 1 
    [mainmeal] => Array ( 
        [0] => Chicken 
        [1] => Fish 
    ) 
    [secondmeal] => Array ( 
        [0] => Chicken 
        [1] => Fish 
    ) 
    [desert] => Array ( 
        [0] => Chocolate Cake 
        [1] => Pumpkin Cheesecake 
    ) 
    [menunotes] => Array ( 
        [0] => 231312321 
        [1] => 231312321 
    ) 
    [to] => myemail@gmail.com 
    [subject] => RSVP form message 
    [submit] => SEND RSVP 
)
```

To add an array I have appended [] to the names of said fields.  Here is my

**processing.php.**

```
$mainmeal = stripslashes($_POST['mainmeal[]']);
    $secondmeal = stripslashes($_POST['secondmeal[]']);
    $desert = stripslashes($_POST['desert[]']);
    $menunotes = stripslashes($_POST['menunotes[]']);
```

Then it puts into an email but I don't know  how to echo out the array.

```
// Let's send the email.
    if(!$error) {
        $messages="From: $email <br>";
        $messages.="Name: $name <br>";
        $messages.="Email: $email <br>";    
        $messages.="Phone: $phone <br>";
        $messages.="Message: $message <br><br>";
        $messages.="No. of guests: $guests <br>";
        $messages.="Meal selection: $mainmeal <br>";
        $messages.="Second Meal selection: $secondmeal <br>";
        $messages.="Desert selection: $desert <br>";
        $messages.="Menu notes: $menunotes <br>";
        $emailto=$to;

        $mail = mail($emailto,$subject,$messages,"from: $from <$Reply>\nReply-To: $Reply \nContent-type: text/html");   

        if($mail) {
            echo 'success';
            print_r($_POST);
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="error">'.$error.'</div>';
    }
```

All the fields name, email phone etc get sent but not the arrays.  How do I make it so it will send the arrays also?

Comment: The `[]` array belongs in your inputs if you intend on using multiple values for the same input(s), not in processing it. Then you'd need a `foreach` and process the key values

Comment: $mainmeal = stripslashes($_POST['mainmeal[]']); remove `[]` brackets from it.  use only stripslashes($_POST['mainmeal']);

Comment: @ShaileshKatarmal `$_POST['mainmeal']` is an array, see this: *...[mainmeal] => Array ( [0] => Chicken [1] => Fish ) ...*

Comment: You can do something like this: `$mainmeal = implode(", ", $_POST['mainmeal']);`

Comment: @ ServerSideSkittles - The question's unclear. But you can try what @RajdeepPaul wrote. We don't know what your inputs look like, or if you are using `foreach` somewhere that you didn't post. Edit: Great, glad to hear it worked.

Comment: Thanks @RajdeepPaul solution worked great.

Comment: @ServerSideSkittles Glad I could help. Cheers! :)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I'd post an answer for it to close it with. *You have my blessing* ;-) or someone else might use your comment to post one with.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure, go ahead. I'll be the first person to upvote it.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Thanks, but I rather not. This one's yours buddy :-) I can't take credit for it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Posted. Cheers buddy! :-)

Comment: All heil the awesome @Fred-ii- !!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `$_POST['mainmeal']`, `$_POST['secondmeal]` etc. are arrays, use `implode()` function to join the array elements, like this:

```
$mainmeal = implode(", ", $_POST['mainmeal']);
$secondmeal = implode(", ", $_POST['secondmeal']);
// so on
```

Here's the reference:

- [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)